# How can I setup capybara with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, bdd

I have capybara and when I run my Featured tests raised an error, it says about pending migrations in test environment, but when a run other type of test everything is good. I've already run all my migrations in test environment, I've already run rails in test and development envs.

this is my gemfile

```
group :development, :test do 
    .... other gems ....
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails'
    gem 'database_cleaner'
    gem 'capybara', '~> 2.5.0'
    gem 'capybara-webkit', '~> 1.7.1'
    gem 'selenium-webdriver'
    gem 'poltergeist'
    gem 'launchy-rails', '~> 0.0.1'
end
```

this is my test

```
# spec/features/sign_in_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Visitor signs up' do

  it "signs me in", :type => :feature do
    visit new_user_session_path
    puts "page:    #{page.html.inspect}"    
    save_and_open_page
  end
end
```

[image]

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I just try with this command:

```
bin/rake db:drop db:create db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
```

Everything is ok with that command. Then I run my server  with: 
`rails s -e test`

Same error in my browser, "ActiveRecord::PendingMigrationError"
http://localhost:3000/

Then I run migrate command
    bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test

But it raised an error "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DuplicateTable: ERROR:  relation "users" already exists"

And same error when a I run the features tests.

Here are my helpers: https://gist.github.com/israelb/e2f4b10ba5f94e1e8df2

Comment: Can you please provide your `rails_helper.rb` and `spec_helper.rb`?

Comment: What happens when you run the suggested bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=tests   ?

Comment: Why are you even running `rails s` in a test environment? O_o

Comment: Only for checking out if the migrations were running well

Answer (score 0):

There may be some kind of migration issue. Try `rake db:test:prepare` see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I was a problem in my config/enviroment/test.rb file, I had to change by this one:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # The test environment is used exclusively to run your application's
  # test suite. You never need to work with it otherwise. Remember that
  # your test database is "scratch space" for the test suite and is wiped
  # and recreated between test runs. Don't rely on the data there!
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Do not eager load code on boot. This avoids loading your whole application
  # just for the purpose of running a single test. If you are using a tool that
  # preloads Rails for running tests, you may have to set it to true.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Configure static file server for tests with Cache-Control for performance.
  config.serve_static_files   = true
  config.static_cache_control = 'public, max-age=3600'

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Raise exceptions instead of rendering exception templates.
  config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false

  # Disable request forgery protection in test environment.
  config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection = false

  # Tell Action Mailer not to deliver emails to the real world.
  # The :test delivery method accumulates sent emails in the
  # ActionMailer::Base.deliveries array.
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test

  # Randomize the order test cases are executed.
  config.active_support.test_order = :random

  # Print deprecation notices to the stderr.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :stderr

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true
end
```